# python identify user input positive or negative

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python code where it will take user input and convert it into uppercase to match my positive list and negative list. but it is not considering the negative list properly. I must be wrong on giving a conditional statement it seems. I tried two codes but not working. also, I tried to sum up how many positive feedbacks and negative feedbacks using `len(words)` but no working at all.

```
 - **code1:**

keyword_list = ['GOOD', 'ADMIRE', 'SUPER', 'BEST', "INCREDIBLE", 'NOT BAD', 'NOT SO BAD', 'KEEP IT UP']
print("Enter your feedback")
user_review = input().upper()
if set(keyword_list).intersection(user_review.split()):
  print ("POSTIVE FEEDBACK")
else:
  print("NEGATIVE FEEDBACK")


- **code2:**

negative_words = ['BAD', 'TERRIBLE','NOT GOOD']
positive_words = ['GOOD', 'ADMIRE', 'SUPER', 'BEST', "INCREDIBLE"]
print("Enter your honest review")
user_review = input().upper()
for review in user_review:
    # split the tweet into words:
    words = review.split()

if set(positive_words).intersection(user_review.split()):
  print ("POSTIVE REVIEW")
elif set(negative_words).intersection(user_review.split()):
  print ("NEGATIVE REVIEW")
else:
  print("MODERATE REVIEW")
```

Comment: You have complicated what could have been a very simple thing.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that  it isn't considering negative reviews properly? What are you expecting?

Comment: @davidlowryduda I mean when I'm trying to give user input as a negative word which is in the list, still it is giving as positive feedback

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug this?

```
set(keyword_list).intersection(['NOT', 'BAD'])
```

This is the results of your

```
set(keyword_list).intersection(user_review.split())
```

with `NOT BAD` as input.

This returns a set with an empty list inside: `set([])`

That's because 'NOT' and 'BAD' are not elements of the set. `NOT BAD` is. If you split the two word elements it won't work.

Anyway, you can achieve your objective in this way

```
negative_words = ['BAD', 'TERRIBLE','NOT GOOD']
positive_words = ['GOOD', 'ADMIRE', 'SUPER', 'BEST', "INCREDIBLE"]
user_review = input("Enter your honest review").upper()
if user_review in positive_words:
    print("POSITIVE REVIEW")
elif user_review in negative_words:
    print("NEGATIVE REVIEW")
```